# Why is my fillRect not showing up on my HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'm following a youtube tutorial and his example works fine, supposed to have a red box i can move with the w, a, s, and d keys. I'm not sure what I missed in this example. I believe the error is in the main.js file, since most changes were made to that file.

```
            //Errors
            keys.js:15 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list 
            main.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined at update (main.js:16) at main (main.js:29)
```

.

```
            // main.js
            var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

            var x = 20, y = 20;

            function init() {
              context.fillStyle = "red";
            }

            function move(dx, dy) {
              x += dx;
              y += dy;
            }

            function update() {
              if(key.a) {move(-5,  0);}
              if(key.d) {move( 5,  0);} // moves sprite 5 in x direction and 0 in y direction
              if(key.w) {move( 0, -5);}
              if(key.s) {move( 0,  5);}
            }

            function draw() {
              context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // clear every pixel from top left to bottom right
              context.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50); //how far from left, top, 50x50
            }

            function main() {

              update();
              draw();
            }

            window.onload = function() {
              init();
              setInterval(main, 1000 / 60); //call main once every 1000/60 milliseconds
            };
```

This is the js that's supposed to handle the keybindings

```
            // keys.js

            var key = {
              a: false,
              d: false,
              s: false,
              w: false
            };

            window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
              switch(event.which || event.keyCode) {
                case 65: key.a = true; break; // 37 <- left
                case 68: key.d = true; break; // 39 <- right
                case 83: key.s = true; break; // 40 <- down
                case 87: key.w = true; break; // 38 <- up
              }
            }};

            window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
              switch(event.which || event.keyCode) {
                case 65: key.a = false; break; // 37 <- left
                case 68: key.d = false; break; // 39 <- right
                case 83: key.s = false; break; // 40 <- down
                case 87: key.w = false; break; // 38 <- up
              }
            }};
```

Comment: please, edit your question to include full *javascript snippet*.

Comment: Are there any errors in the js console?

Comment: @csmckelvey keys.js:15 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
1106main.js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: key is not defined
    at update (main.js:16)
    at main (main.js:29)

Comment: Try including `keys.js` before you include `main.js`. Also your call is: `window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {..}}` when it should be `window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {..})` Notice the last `}` should be `)` for both `keydown` and `keyup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `key` is undefined it is likely due to them being in separate files and included out of order. Try including your `keys.js` before `main.js` in whatever file is hosting the two.

As for this error: `keys.js:15 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

The problem is your `addEventListener` function call. Both of them end in `}};` when it should be `});`. See below:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  switch(event.which || event.keyCode) {
    case 65: key.a = true; break; // 37 <- left
    case 68: key.d = true; break; // 39 <- right
    case 83: key.s = true; break; // 40 <- down
    case 87: key.w = true; break; // 38 <- up
  }
}); // <-- Corrected

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  switch(event.which || event.keyCode) {
    case 65: key.a = false; break; // 37 <- left
    case 68: key.d = false; break; // 39 <- right
    case 83: key.s = false; break; // 40 <- down
    case 87: key.w = false; break; // 38 <- up
  }
}); // <-- Corrected
```

Comment: It was just that parenthesis which needed to be changed. The program works as intended now. Thanks so much!